# How would I make a "3D-looking" panel in Unity2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a "panel" (I mean a plate, not the UI element) in Unity2D that looks 3D: that is, it seems to be recessed, with shadow/highlighting around the edges. I'll attach an image of a simple version.

I can kinda do it by putting three UI panels atop each other, of slightly different sizes and offsets and of different shades of gray (3, not 50 [grin]), but it doesn't scale for different resolutions properly.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Model such a plate and put a world space ui on it

Comment: This looks like it could be achieved via a simple [9-sliced sprite](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/9SliceSprites.html) and selecting Sliced instead of Simple in the sprite renderer

Comment: 9-slice was exactly what I needed! Thanks Erik! (How do I "upvote" you on this board?)